# Validate function of IValidatableObject not working

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2

I have a "Review" Class:

```
public class Review : IValidatableObject
{
    public int ReviewId { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Digning Date")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }

    [Range(1, 10)]
    public int Rating { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public int RestaurantId { get; set; }
    public virtual Restaurant Resturant { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var fields = new[]{ "Created"};

        if(Created > DateTime.Now)
        {
            yield return new ValidationResult("Created date cannot be in the future.", fields);
        }

        if (Created < DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1))
        {
            yield return new ValidationResult("Created date cannot be to far in the past.", fields);
        }
    }
}
```

which uses Validate method of IValidatableObject to validate Create property. also this is my cshtml code:

```
@model OdeToFood.Models.Review

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

@section scripts
 {
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript">      </script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")"    type="text/javascript"></script>
}

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
<fieldset>
    <legend>Review</legend>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Created)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Created)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Created)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Rating)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Rating)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Rating)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Body)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Body)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Body)
    </div>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
}

<div>
@Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

The Validate method simply check wether the year of date of Create is in present year(2012) or last year(2011). So if user enter 2000 as year he should get error: "Created date cannot be in the future.". But i does not work!

also this is my configuration in web.config:

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="webpages:Version" value="1.0.0.0" />
  <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
  <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
</appSettings>
```

also this my controller code:

```
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View(new Review());
    } 

    //
    // POST: /Reviews/Create

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(int restaurantId, Review newReview)
    {
        try
        {
            //_db is my DBContext
            var restaurant = _db.Restaurants.Single(r => r.RestaurantId == restaurantId);
            newReview.Created = DateTime.Now;

            restaurant.Reviews.Add(newReview);
            _db.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch(System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException ex)
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

What i must to do?
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried debugging to see if the Validate method is getting called? Can you also post your controller Action method code for this view, please.

Comment: @PaulTaylor i debugged. The validate method executed twice! In the first execution it validate, but in second it doesn't validate!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's getting called twice because once when you post and the model binder binds to newReview, and once when you call SaveChanges.

What you should do is when you post check if ModelState.IsValid= false, if so return View(newReview);

in addition your DbEntityValidationException should return View(newReview);

and lastly check out the action filter I wrote here - you don't need to have a try catch - simply use the attribute on your controller's method or register it on application startup like is done with HandleError

[MapEntityExceptionsToModelErrorsAttribute](https://github.com/adamtuliper/EF5-for-Real-Web-Applications/blob/master/Gecko.Framework.Mvc/ActionFilters/MapEntityExceptionsToModelErrorsAttribute.cs)